# ASP Classic DSN ADODB get error with password in access-db

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, odbc, windows-server, dsn

I had to migrate an old ASP-System (oh yeah) with Database as Access-DB.
There is an System-DSN over Microsoft Access database engine 2010 (it's so old that I use this and not 2016). Old System is Windows Serve 2012 (also with Db engine 2010 driver), new system is Server 2022 both this IIS-Server and ASP active.

Normally the Access-DB has a accesspassword by opening ("examplepass"). But when I create the connection with password I get an error:
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers Error "80004005''
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver for Microsoft Access] No allowed password.

Yes, the password is correct. ;-)

When Access-DB has no password and I used this code, everything works:

```
Dim objConn, pass
pass = "examplepass"
Session.Timeout=15
Set objConn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.ConnectionString="DSN=MyDSNname;pwd=" & pass
objConn.Open



objConn.Close
set objConn = nothing
```

In DSN I could also notice the password, it doesn't matter if there is a password or not, the failure is everytime there, when Access-DB has a password in.
Same code in the old system with password, it works also.

I don't know, because on the old system it works with password an the same code
Have you an idea? Could you help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is:
I used now the "newst" driver (Microsoft Access database engine 2016). Than it works.
It is a little bit confusing, because on the old system only the old driver works.